# RTL8180 kernel module freezing with Realtek RTL8185L chipset

Tags: wifi, freeze, drivers

I've recently purchased a PEAK wireless PCI board. I needed a card with removable antenna capability to test a high gain antenna that I had laying around. Went to my local hardware store and I got this one.

It comes with a RTL8185L chip.

In the times of kernel 2.6, Realtek had a [driver](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=1&PFid=1&Level=6&Conn=5&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#RTL8185L) that seamed to have solved the problem.

I've downloaded that one, but it does not compile under kernel 3.10 (Yes, i was going for wishful thinking).

My box is a Slackware 14.0 (updated from current) with kernel 3.10.5-smp.

Has anyone had any issue with kernel module rtl8180 freezing the system after an `ifconfig wlanN up`?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a very old issue that hasn't been resolved. Blacklisting this device seems to be the only thing you can do currently.

- [wifi module rtl8180 freezes the system](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/368679)
- [bringing up 10ec:8185 wifi module freezes the system](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/839019)

Comment: Well, blacklisting the device sure removes the freeze, it does not, however, solve the problem of using the card. Looks like the only way forward is to port the 2.6 kernel code from Realtek to something more 3.x. Alas, I'm not the one to do it.

Comment: @GustavoCarreno - sorry I couldn't find anything that showed howto get that card to work.

Comment: I know, my friend, I had the same problem while Googling for the problem. Hence me asking here, so the experts are aware of it :)